# Menu alternando quando clico em menu one ele me mostra o item two

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const itemLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.header-item')
const navHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu')

for (let i = 0; i < itemLinks.length; i++) {
    itemLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        for (let i = 0; i < navHeader.length; i++) {
            navHeader[i].classList.toggle('active')
        }
        navHeader[i].classList.remove('active')
    })
}
```

```css
.nav-menu.active{
    display: block;
}
.nav-menu{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one" class="header-item header-item--one">menu one</a>
<a href="#two" class="header-item header-item--two">menu two</a> 

<nav class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item one</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item two</li>
        <li>Item two</li>
        <li>Item two</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que dessa forma resolva:

```
const itemLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.header-item')
const navHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu')

for (let i = 0; i < itemLinks.length; i++) {
    itemLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // usei uma variável diferente para ficar mais legível e permitir a posterior comparação de indíces
        for (let ii = 0; ii < navHeader.length; ii++) {
          if (ii !== i) // checa para manter o "estado" (classe active) do menu clicado
            navHeader[ii].classList.remove('active')
        }
        navHeader[i].classList.toggle('active'); // com o "estado" mantido, é possível usar toggle
    })
}
```

Explicando, removi todos os estados no loop para depois dar toggle do menu clicado, fazendo com que apareça se estiver invisível ou fique invisível se visível.

O trecho de código abaixo fica confuso, pois a keyword `let` faz com a variável so exista no escopo do loop `for`, diferente de quando se usa `var`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < itemLinks.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Valeu anderson obrigado ai mano resolveu!!